# Image Coloring In C#

Tags: c#, graphics, gdi+, imaging

I want to recolor an Image in C# such that it preserves the real image (just as we do in any Photo Editor). I am trying to do this but of no use. Can anybody help me in this regard...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

namespace Images
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try 
        {
            Bitmap img = new Bitmap(@"D:\Image\Chrysanthemum.jpg");
            Bitmap NewImage = new Bitmap(img,img.Width,img.Height);
            for (int i = 0; i < img.Width; i++)
            {

                for (int j = 0; j < img.Height; j++)
                {
                    {

                        NewImage.SetPixel(i, j,Color.FromArgb(0,0,240,0));

                    }
                 }
            }
             NewImage.MakeTransparent();

                            NewImage.Save(@"D:\Image\1",System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

           }
        catch(System.Exception exc)
        {
            Console.Write(exc);
        }
    }

   }
   }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Or is the new image you saved not what you expected?

Comment: As far as I can see you will just create a second image with a quite green color, right?

Comment: Side notes: `using (Bitmap NewImage = new ...) {...}` (put `IDisposable` into `using`); do not *swallow* exceptions via `catch(System.Exception exc) {Console.Write(exc);}`

Comment: @Waescher The alpha component is set to 0. As far as I can tell, this won't do anything to the image.

Comment: @Phylogenesis you're right, my fault :)

Comment: Also, JPEG/JFIF has no alpha component. Anything you may be trying to do with transparency will be lost when saving the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do **Color Modulation**, the right approach would be to iterate through each pixel of the image, represent each `RGB` value as a `float` from `0.0f` to `1.0f`, then **multiply** it by the color you want it to have.

```
using System.Drawing;

namespace stuff
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Bitmap pImage = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\...\Desktop\test.jpg");
            Bitmap pModified = new Bitmap(pImage.Width, pImage.Height);

            Color tintColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0);

            for (int x = 0; x < pImage.Width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < pImage.Height; y++)
                {
                    //Calculate the new color
                    var oldColor = pImage.GetPixel(x, y);
                    byte red =(byte)(256.0f * (oldColor.R / 256.0f) * (tintColor.R / 256.0f));
                    byte blue = (byte)(256.0f * (oldColor.B / 256.0f) * (tintColor.B / 256.0f));
                    byte green = (byte)(256.0f * (oldColor.G / 256.0f) * (tintColor.G / 256.0f));

                    Color newColor = Color.FromArgb(red, blue, green);
                    pModified.SetPixel(x, y, newColor);
                }
            }
            pModified.Save(@"C:\Users\...\Desktop\tint.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        }
    }
}
```

Input:
[image: in]

Output:
[image: out]

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is just creating a second image with the same size of the original one. This second image is filled with a green color (but no alpha - so it's just transparent). I suspect that you hoped for the method `MakeTransparent()` to recolor the original image but this is not the case. This method will just make pixels of a certain color transparent. This is not the image's opacity.

So these are two images - one beside the other, they have nothing to do with each other (besides of the same size).

So you could manipulate the image in the `img` variable directly (you may copy it to preserve the original one) by creating a `Graphics` object from your `img` with which you can draw a semi-transparent color over the image.

```
using (var gfx = Graphics.FromImage(img))
{
    using (var brush = new SolidBrush(MYCOLOR)
        gfx.FillRect(brush, MYRECT)
}
```

**But I would heavily insist that you use a image processing library** for the image manipulation you want to achieve. So please check the free [imageprocessor.org](http://imageprocessor.org/). Their [hue filter](http://imageprocessor.org/imageprocessor/imagefactory/hue/) might be what you want to have.